# Binding a form to another process's window

Tags: c#, winforms

For my project, I require to bind my Winform to another process's window, in this case the browser's page that has a title "Client", so that it's only able to move it in that window. What would be the best and steady way to do this?

I've tried getting the window process by title, which succeeded. I got the window rect by using getWindowRect method but this didn't really seem to work as the form would not correctly bind to the form.

```
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, this.windowTitle);
RECT rect1;
GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rect1);

RECT rect2;
GetWindowRect(this.Handle, out rect2);

if (!(rect2.Y >= rect1.Y && rect2.Y + rect2.Height <= rect1.Y + rect1.Height && rect2.X >= rect1.X && rect2.X + rect2.Width <= (rect1.X + rect1.Width) - (rect1.Width / 3)))
{
Console.WriteLine("You can't leave the window with this form! Naughty!");
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) && [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx)

Comment: I've tried getting the window process by title, which succeeded. I got the window rect by using getWindowRect method but this didn't really seem to get the correct outcome as the coordinates where weird.

Comment: what do you mean by "binding" ?

Comment: I've added the code which I've already tried, maybe it clarifies things. With binding I mean that the form isn't able to leave the boudns of the window it is bound to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!(rect2.Y >= rect1.Y && rect2.Y + rect2.Height <= rect1.Y + rect1.Height ...
```

Clearly your declaration for RECT is bogus.  It doesn't have a Height or Width property, it doesn't behave like the .NET Rectangle type.  Always double-check your pinvoke declarations with good sources like the pinvoke.net website or the Pinvoke Interop Assistant tool.   A proper declaration is:

```
private struct RECT {
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}
```

Adjust your if() statement accordingly.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Also, thanks for the website. It is indeed a great source and I have favourited it and will make sure to check it every time!